# How can I convert IEnumerable method to work asynchronously

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, yield

I'm using c#, .net 6.0

I'm trying to convert IEnumerable method and ot's caller method to work asynchronously.

I have a code that looks something like that:

```
    public IEnumerable<MyUser> getUsers()
    {
        return AccountById
            .Keys
            .SelectMany(accountId => {
                try
                {
                    return getUsersFor(accountId)
                        .Select(x => new MyUser(x,
                            SetAccountUniqueName(AccountById[accountId].Name,
                                AccountById[accountId].Id)));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _log.Error(ex);
                    return Enumerable.Empty<MyUser>();
                }
            });
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> getUsersFor(string accountId)
    {
        ListUsersResponse usersResponse;
        string marker = null;
        do
        {
            using (var myClient = new ServiceClient(pass))
            {
                usersResponse =
                    myClient.ListUsersAsync(
                            new ListUsersRequest { Marker = marker, MaxItems = MAX_ITEMS })
                        .Result;
                foreach (var user in usersResponse.Users)
                {
                    yield return user;
                }
            }

            marker = usersResponse.Marker;
        } while (usersResponse.IsTruncated);
    }
```

How can I convert getUsers() and getUsersFor() to async methods?

Comment: Follow c# convention when naming your methods,method names Should be in PascalCase.

Comment: It's not appropriate to edit your question into an entirely different question once it's been answered.  If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm missing something, you just need to change your signature from

```
 public IEnumerable<User> getUsersFor(string accountId)
```

to

```
 public async IAsyncEnumerable<User> getUsersFor(string accountId)
```

and remove the call to `.Result` in your async methods and await them:

```
usersResponse = await myClient
    .ListUsersAsync(new ListUsersRequest { Marker = marker, MaxItems = MAX_ITEMS });
```

Comment: This gives an error - The body of 'getUsersFor(string)' cannot be an iterator block because 'Task<IEnumerable<User>>' is not an iterator interface type

Comment: Try `public async IAsyncEnumerable<User> getUsersFor(string accountId)` instead

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove `.Result` and change methods to be asynchronous with `async` and `await` keywords and change return types to `Task<IEnumerable<MyUser>>` and `Task<IEnumerable<User>>`.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyUser>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    var result = new List<MyUser>();

    foreach(var accountId in AccountById.Keys)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await GetUsersForAsync(accountId);
            result.Add(new MyUser(user, SetAccountUniqueName(AccountById[accountId].Name,
                            AccountById[accountId].Id)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                _log.Error(ex);
                return Enumerable.Empty<MyUser>();
        }
    }
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsersForAsync(string accountId)
{
    ListUsersResponse usersResponse;
    string marker = null;
    do
    {
        using (var myClient = new ServiceClient(pass))
        {
            usersResponse =
                await myClient.ListUsersAsync(
                        new ListUsersRequest { Marker = marker, MaxItems = MAX_ITEMS });

            foreach (var user in usersResponse.Users)
            {
                yield return user;
            }
        }

        marker = usersResponse.Marker;
    } while (usersResponse.IsTruncated);
}
```

Comment: This gives an error - The body of 'getUsersFor(string)' cannot be an iterator block because 'Task<IEnumerable<User>>' is not an iterator interface type

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to change return types. Try now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you changed but I still get the same error (and also error from the "Select"...)

Comment: Another update. foreach instead of LINQ.